# How to list any package update on specific time space?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-history

**Suppose this situation:**
There is a sudden problem on my Ubuntu system that was working properly. After trying various approach to solve the problem, I guess that a package update caused the problem.
I know the exact date and time of first occurrence of the problem and also know that the problem was not present just 1 hour before that time. Now, I need to know if there was any package updated in this 1 hour time space.
Is there any command that list any package updates in a specific time space?

Comment: I don't think so, but there are useful log files in /var/log/apt that you can have a look at, with dates and times of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run the following commands which will print timestamps and changes:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log
```

and

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

I think you are looking for the first one as that should show all changes made through dpkg and not just the manual apt-get commands run like the second one does although they are both helpful.